# Alternate to HTML iframes

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know what the below kind of frames are called. I guess they are not iframes as they don't show me the option to "Reload this frame" on making right click and I don't think that they are hidden DIV layers as layers will load data with direct page load. Can anybody tell me what the below kind of frames are called and how the information is loaded after clicking on its related button. Is that any javascript if so what's the keyword to google it?

[image: Sample 1]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just div elements from html. When you click the button the content is dynamicly loaded by AJAX. This could be raw AJAX or some library like jQuery.

So I guess you would google "AJAX load div content"

Answer (score 1):

The techniques for loading additional data from the server without leaving the current page are collectively known as [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Inserting content retrieved via Ajax into the document is done using [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Well, Quentin I know about Ajax I am asking for the term that is used to find more about my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't frames at all. Those are divs, held in place over the other elements using CSS. The content is loaded using AJAX. Read more about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax)